# Circumvent Array size > Integer.MAX_VALUE for BufferedImage?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am using a Java program for some image processing and currently I am working with some rather large images (on the order of a gigapixel).

Not surprisingly, I have been unable to do much, due to the following exception:

```
Exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Array size > Integer.MAX_VALUE!
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:1064)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2879)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1046)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1014)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1282)
...
```

I am wondering if there is any way I might circumvent this limit by overloading the BufferedImage class with another compatible class that supports large images?

Comment: Are you using any library for image processing. Or if it's your code, you can change to BigDecimal instead of integer

Comment: Use an ImageReader and use an ImageReadParam with [setSourceRegion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/IIOParam.html#setSourceRegion%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) to work piece wise. Then use memory mapped I/O of colours with ByteBuffer. _Not sure this suffices._

Comment: Do you pass any value to `setDestination` or `setDestinationType`? If so, what value? You should be able to create a gigapixel size image, using any of the `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_XXX` types (given your heap is big enough of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the array size limit is hard-wired in the JVM and java specification.

To solve your problem, you will need to abstract from simple images and rasters. A large image can be subdivided into multiple smaller images, each containing only a small rectangular section of the large image.

This will not help you with the exception you got there though. There is nothing you can do about the way ImageIO handles images internally (besides possibly registering the limitation as a bug). You will need to find an alternate library for reading images of *that* size, or code it yourself (a lot of work to be sure).

EDIT: Creating a subclass of BufferedImage won't help you, BufferedImage is only a thin facade to the underlying structures (Raster, DataBuffer) which are ultimately hard-wired to use arrays for storage. And you would still have the problem ImageIO creating instances of the original BufferedImage class.

Comment: While the maximum array size is absolute, the maximum size of an image depends on its transfer type (the native array type). As an example, using a type similar to `TYPE_INT_RGB`, you will be able to create an image about 3 times as large compared to `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`. Theoretically, you should be able to use `long` as a transfer type too (packing more pixels into each array element), but I've never seen anyone do this...

Comment: PS: You can pass a pre-allocated image to `ImageIO` (using `ImageReadParam.setDestination(..)`), if you want to use a specific subtype of `BufferedImage`. This, compared with tiling (`ImageReadParam.setSourceRegion(..)`) should give you some flexibility. So stating *"there is nothing you can do"* is a little rushed. ;-)

Comment: @HaraldK You may want to research a bit deeper into how DataBuffer's handle the different pixel models You will *not* be able to pack more pixels into TYPE_INT_RGB than any of the BYTE_XXX-types. Look at the concrete sub classes in java.awt.image. The reason for this is that a DataBuffer is organized into *bands*  (color components) in case of the byte types. Each band is allocated as a separate array, so in regards to the maximum number of pixels, there is no difference between the types BYTE and INT.

Comment: That depends on the sample model. Most modern displays are optimized for "interleaved" access, and the standard BI `TYPE_BYTE_*` types are all interleaved (RGBRGBRGB... as single array/band) rather than banded (RRR, GGG, BBB as distinct arrays/bands). But you are right, it doesn't depend only on the transfer type. And using a banded sample model (and raster) would allow you to create just as large image as with `TYPE_INT_*`. Even if there's no standard type for it. :-)

Comment: @HaraldK You're mixing up hardware capabilities and AWT API-constraints. ByteBuffer is not interleaved (take a look at its implementation). There is simply no way to specify it when creating it and also there are no data members to express interleaved mode. Don't think of the Image/Raster/DataBuffer as an image that can necessarily be processed by hardware. Its an abstraction and it isn't required to be used to display it directly (although the JRE *may* access the DataBuffer's backing array directly in specially managed cases).

Comment: `ByteBuffer` (or `DataBufferByte`, really) is just a buffer. It supports both banded and interleaved operation. Banded uses one bank per band, interleaved typically a single bank. But you don't specify interleaved (or banded), it's the `SampleModel`s responsibility to control how samples are stored in the buffer. In any case, don't take my word for it. Look at the `BufferedImage` constructor, and see that the  `TYPE_xBYTE_*` types all use `Raster.createInterleavedRaster`. Using a banded sample model will always result in `TYPE_CUSTOM` BI. :-)

Comment: @HaraldK Oops, I missed that. You're right the SampleModel can use a ByteBuffer in interleaved organization without the ByteBuffer knowing about it.